# CMake link installed shared library

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I am new to CMake and have been trying to structure my project so that I build a shared library (game engine) that can then be linked to one or more executables (games). My directory structure is as follows:

```
- build
- engine
- - include
- - source
- game
- - include
- - source
- resources
- scripts
```

I have managed to install the shared library with the command:

```
install(TARGETS Engine
  EXPORT Engine
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install(EXPORT Engine DESTINATION lib)
```

This creates the following file: build/engine/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/Engine.cmake

How can I include this file so that I can link my Engine library with my Game executable?
I had hoped that it was just a case of using `find_package(Engine REQUIRED)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the .cmake file.

After your `add_executable` for the game executable, add the following assuming your game engines target name is Game:

```
target_link_libraries(Game Engine)
```

cmake will do all the magic behind the scenes making sure that the engine is built before the game and then link the game to the engine for you.